# Can't install Ubuntu, Windows installs fine, getting: hardlink error on install

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, uefi

My boy William (7) is building a computer and wanted to try out Linux.  Windows installed just fine no problems.  But it seems that all versions of linux we try (last attempt was the 20.04 Beta).  We are using rufus to create a bootable USB drive and we can get to GRUB but when we try to install we get the error:

"Initramfs unpacking failed: Decoding Failed" 
then 
ln: /tmp/mountroot-fail-hooks.d/scripts/init-premount/lvm2: no such file or directory

https://photos.app.goo.gl/4PGBpcriAD3GYFkq9
[Error When booting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XMWhh.jpg)

I've gone into the BIOS and made sure CSM was disabled.  Nothing seems to work and we are always back here.  We tried Mint and that doesn't work either to install it BUT i can live boot with it.

Googling I found: 
https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/stuck-reboot-%40-busybox-v1-21-1-then-initramfs-prompt-plz-help-4175540745/

But that doesn't look like a complete match.

I did eventually let the

"stdin: Invalid argument" run through for a while and I eventually get to BusyBox

I took a shot of what is showing as mounted:
https://photos.app.goo.gl/DiXo6ZBXHy4kQzUP8

it has:
rootfs
sysfs
proc
udev
devpts
tmpfs

Any advice would be greatly appreciated and make me look like a hero to my boy.

**Hardware:**
Processor: Ryzen 7 2700X

Motherboard: Asus ROG Strix B450-F

Graphics: Nvidia GeForce RTX 2060

HD: Samsung SSD (NVME) 970 EVO 500GB

Memory: 32Gigs (past windows memory diagnostic)

https://photos.app.goo.gl/iVPHP19oDzLAKf5f7

Bios UEFI mode

more hardware info here gather from Windows: 
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1gSmbbN7vsH902gd4uWMLiRauCgrVSJHd/view?usp=sharing

Thank you in Advance,

Ted

Comment: Refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic where you'll notice only supported releases of Ubuntu and flavors are on-topic for this site. For 20.04 questions you'll need to use a development support site such as IRC (#ubuntu+1) or Ubuntu Forums, or wait until after release for this site (expected release date for Ubuntu 20.04 is 23rd April 2020 when your question will be on-topic here).

Comment: I'm not familiar with your issue, but did you verify your install media (thumb-drive or whatever you are using) on another box?  ie. boot it selecting "Check disk for errors" to ensure the media itself was correctly written.

Comment: You'd be better off trying Ubuntu 18.04 which is supported here. Also, you can include images here itself by clicking the image icon above the posting area.

Comment: ok a few updates....I tried installing on another machine and everything worked great, so I don't think it is the usb drive or the image.  I also tried 18.04 as per recommendation and now it is sending a trace:  https://photos.app.goo.gl/RwaJotiNe74JeGLv5 that is with the acpi=off flag on the boot, when I don't include it I get: https://photos.app.goo.gl/VDRnE8YE767oXW4t8 so still lost as to what the issue is.  It must be some sort of missing driver for the nvme drives or a problem with something hardware specific.  Any ideas where to look next?

Answer (score 2):

Solved with latest BIOS update for some reason the BIOS favored windows until enough people complained.